# How can i concatenate two different list<T> where both have same base class?

Tags: c#, generics, collections

I have a class called `ItemChange<T>` that looks like this:

```
public class ItemChange<T> where T : MyBase
{
    public DateTime When { get; set; }
    public string Who { get; set; }
    public T NewState;
    public T OldState;
}
```

As you can see it stores two copies of an object (`NewState` and `OldState`). I use this to compare field changes.

I now am trying to get this to work where I get a list of changes across multiple objects and then concatenate a few different types of T list into one array like this (NOTE: both `Object1` and `Object2` derive from `MyBase`:

```
public IEnumerable<ItemChange<T>> GetChangeHistory<T>(int numberOfChanges) where T : MyBase
{
    IEnumerable<ItemChange<Object1>> obj1Changes= GetChanges<Object1>();
    IEnumerable<ItemChange<Object2>> obj1Changes= GetChanges<Object2>();
    return obj1Changes.Concat(obj2Changes).OrderByDescending(r => r.When).Take(numberofChanges);
}
```

As you can see I need to concatenate changes from multiple types but then I want to grab the most recent number of changes (defined by `numberOfChanges`)

Any suggestions for how I could get the below to work as the Concat line gives me a compiler error (I assume I have to cast in some special way to get this to work).

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Please see ["Stack Overflow does not allow tags in titles"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles/130208#130208).

Comment: Have you tried to cast to `(IEnumerable<ItemChange<MyBase>>)obj2Changes` ?

Comment: maybe something like this? `return obj1Changes.Cast<ItemChange<MyBase>>().Concat(obj2Changes.Cast<ItemChange<MyBase>>()).OrderByDescending(r => r.When).Take(numberofChanges);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend adding a base class to `ItemChange<T>` called `ItemChange`. The `ItemChange` can declare the When property. Then it becomes pretty easy to cast the list contents to the base `ItemChange` for concat and order by.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace brosell
{

public class MyBase
{

}

public class ItemChange
{
    public DateTime When { get; set; }

}

public class ItemChange<T>: ItemChange where T : MyBase
{
    public string Who { get; set; }
    public T NewState;
    public T OldState;
}

public class Sub1: MyBase
{

}

public class Sub2: MyBase
{

}

   public class HelloWorld
   {
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<ItemChange<Sub1>> listOfSub1 = new List<ItemChange<Sub1>>();
        List<ItemChange<Sub2>> listOfSub2 = new List<ItemChange<Sub2>>();

        var concated = listOfSub1.Cast<ItemChange>().Concat(listOfSub2.Cast<ItemChange>());

        var filtered = concated.OrderByDescending(ic => ic.When).Take(10);  

        Console.WriteLine("{0}", filtered.Count());
        }
   } 
}
```

Comment: Of course now the challenge is to figure out what your resulting filtered list actually contains! I would give thought to refactoring the architecture to better represent the business logic. For example, why does ItemChange<T> even need to know what changed?

Answer (score 1):

How about this? I am not sure because I cannot test it now.

```
public IEnumerable<ItemChange<T>> GetChangeHistory<T>(int numberOfChanges) where T : MyBase
{
    IEnumerable<ItemChange<MyBase>> obj1Changes = GetChanges<Object1>().Select(i => new ItemChange<MyBase>(){ When = i.When, Who = i.Who, NewState = i.NewState, OldState = i.OldState });
    IEnumerable<ItemChange<MyBase>> obj1Changes = GetChanges<Object2>().Select(i => new ItemChange<MyBase>(){ When = i.When, Who = i.Who, NewState = i.NewState, OldState = i.OldState });
    return obj1Changes.Concat(obj2Changes).OrderByDescending(r => r.When).Take(numberofChanges);
}
```

It creates a new instance of `ItemChange<MyBase>` from `ItemChange<Object1>` or `ItemChange<Object2>`.

Depending on your usage, you may want to add `.ToList()` to the end of the Linq to increase performance.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is not safe since there is no conversion between an `ItemChange<Object1>` and an `ItemChange<Object2>`, and there is certainly no conversion to some arbitrary `ItemChange<T>`. The best you can try to do is `ItemChange<MyBase>` but classes are not covariant in C# so this is not valid:

```
ItemChange<MyBase> change = new ItemChange<Object1>();
```

You therefore cannot cast an `IEnumerable<ItemChange<Object1>>` to an `IEnumerable<ItemChange<Object2>>`.

However if you create an interface for your `ItemChange<T>` class then you can do it safely:

```
public interface IItemChange<out T> where T : MyBase
{
    DateTime When { get; set; }
    string Who { get; set; }
    T NewState { get; }
    T OldState { get; }
}

public class ItemChange<T> : IItemChange<T> where T : MyBase
{
    public DateTime When { get; set; }
    public string Who { get; set; }
    public T NewState { get; set; }
    public T OldState { get; set; }
}
```

You can then change your `GetChanges` and `GetChangeHistory` methods to:

```
private static IEnumerable<IItemChange<T>> GetChanges<T>() where T : MyBase { ... }

public static IEnumerable<IItemChange<MyBase>> GetChangeHistory(int numberOfChanges)
{
    IEnumerable<IItemChange<MyBase>> obj1Changes = GetChanges<Object1>();
    IEnumerable<IItemChange<MyBase>> obj2Changes = GetChanges<Object2>();
    return obj1Changes.Concat(obj2Changes).OrderByDescending(r => r.When).Take(numberOfChanges);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you defined an interface `IReadableItemChange<out T>` which exposed read-only properties of type `T` rather than fields of that type, and if `ItemChange<T>` implemented `IReadableItemChange<T>`, then both `ItemChange<Derived1>` and `ItemChange<Derived2>` would implement `IReadableItemChange<MyBase>` (and, incidentally, `IReadableItemChange<baseType>` for any `baseType` such that `Derived1:baseType` and `Derived2:baseType`).  It may be helpful as well for `ItemChange<T>` to have a constructor which accepts an `IReadableItemChange<T>` and copies the data from it.